# AdMob's RewardedVideoAd destroys activity it was started from after video is watched

Tags: android

I am using AdMob's RewardedVideoAd.

What I've done is when user opens a chat activity, I ask him to view a video to be able to chat to another user (by simply switching visibility of the chat elements).  Then, after the video is watched, I make the chat elements visible. 
It works well on the emulator. However, when I tested it on my phone, the chat activity is closed after video is watched. I cannot understand why this is happening.

It **only** happens if a user watches the video till the end (onRewarded() is called).

Any suggestions?

Comment: can you show code that you do for AdMob.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I worked it out.

It happened, because I did not forward the lifecycle events. After I called resume(context), pause(c), destroy(c) according to my Activity lifecycle, it worked.

God knows why it worked fine on the emulator and did not on my phone.